# Dovecot quota doesn't reject incoming emails when quota is exceeded

Tags: vps, dovecot, centos7

I've got VPS under CentOS 7 with Exim+Dovecot mail system.

```
cat /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf
mail_privileged_group = mail
mail_access_groups = mail
mail_location = maildir:%h/mail/%d/%n
pop3_uidl_format = %08Xu%08Xv
mail_plugins = $mail_plugins quota
```

---

```
cat /etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-imap.conf
##
## IMAP specific settings
##

protocol imap {
mail_plugins = $mail_plugins autocreate imap_quota    
}

plugin {
  autocreate = Trash
  autocreate2 = Spam
  autocreate3 = Sent
  autocreate4 = Drafts
  #autocreate5 = Custom
  autosubscribe = Trash
  autosubscribe2 = Spam
  autosubscribe3 = Sent
  autosubscribe4 = Drafts
  #autosubscribe5 = Custom
}
```

---

```
cat /etc/dovecot/conf.d/90-quota.conf
plugin {
  quota = dict:User quota::file:%h/dovecot-quota
    quota_rule = *:storage=10M:messages=1000
    }
```

And *doveadm* command returns this:

```
doveadm quota get -u temp@atago.ru
Quota name Type    Value Limit    %
User quota STORAGE 11620 10240   113
User quota MESSAGE     4  1000   0
```

How to configure Dovecot so that it won't allow to deliver emails when mailbox is 100% full?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use limit Exim mail capacity, or the ask Exim to use Dovecot to distribute the email. In your case, the quota is only applied when a user try to upload a mail by drag-n'drop from its PC to the IMAP server.

Look at http://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA/Exim

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `quota` plugin not only for `imap` protocol but for `lda` protocol too, as far as at LDA stage quota is tested against current maildir size.

```
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = autocreate quota imap_quota    
  . . . . .
}

protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = quota 
  . . . . .
}
```